# How does Jim know there is a secret door?

Tags: plot-explanation, 28-days-later

In *28 Days Later*, when they end up at the mansion with the military guys,  Jim goes on a rampage and sets free the infected. He ends up being chased by them and runs into a room where he proceeds to a corner and disappears into a secret door in the wall.

How does he know that door is there?

There must be an answer in the deleted scenes?

Comment: I know exactly what you are talking about. I just assumed he had been in the building long enough he had a good understanding of the building. Maybe someone has a more definitive answer than that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer has to be that during his time in the mansion he somehow found out.

It's not shown on the screen at any time and it's not mentioned in any DVD commentary. Therefore, barring him discovering it completely by chance (which really would be impressive!) the only remaining plausible explanation is that he came across it at some point during his stay in the mansion.

Even this explanation isn't great (so the soldiers who were planning to rape his companions showed him the secret door?), but it's the only logical one.

Comment: I think you're right and that really gets me. No explanation at all. Oh well. As someone said, movies are art and are composed of many moving parts. Something is bound to get missed.

Comment: Yeah - it's unfortunate that these things are missed. I've reviewed so many questions on this site already which point out really good flaws that just have no answer other than "movie mistake", or "lack of explanation".